# joomla + virtuemart or drupal + ubercart for simple cms + small online shop?

Tags: php, content-management-system, shopping-cart

I have to create a small website (about 10 pages) with a very small shop (about 20 products).

Both won't change much and its really a small project.

I thought about using joomla + virtuemart or drupal + ubercart. Does anybody have experience with both? I would like to know which one is the better choice or if there is something else that would be even better for such a small cms/shop setup.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the customer require a payment gateway? I ask because you've mentioned several CMSs and referenced ubercart for use as a CMS, but not as a payment solution.

If you do not require a payment gateway (i.e., if you're not going to be a actually selling directly from the website but rather referring customers to a phone or mail or some such), then I would recommend Drupal or Joomla from the options given. Joomla is faster to wrap one's head around and so is quicker to set up, but it is much less flexible when compared to Drupal.

Drupal, which I have a strong personal preference for, offers much more in the way of plugins / extensibility, and also has tight ubercart integration available (which I've used to great success on a few projects). If you have a need to create pages in addition to the content page (e.g. a home/ splash page, contact, about, blogs, forums, etc.), then Drupal will (IMHO) serve you much better. Further, it is highly themeable.

Using either Joomla or Drupal, you are likely to be able to set up a site of the simplicity you describe without needing to code anything from scratch.

If the content really is non-dynamic and expected to remain more-or-less static for extended periods, and/or if it is desirable to "get-er'-done" quickly, and if you don't mind coding from scratch, you might consider coding static html pages that reference one of the payment solutions mentioned by DamnYankee, redconservatory, et al.

Comment: Thank you! Well I require a payment gateway but that will also be possible with joomla and drupal, wouldnt it? I think I will go for drupal+uebercart, it might be useful for future projects too.

Comment: Indeed, there are gateway solutions for either CMS, and many to choose from!

Note that ubercart does add a layer of complexity to the application; if you don't need inventory controls or shopping carts, you might consider not using it at all (e.g. build up Drupal content types for the products and include links to pay-pal). That being said, once you get past UberCart's learning curve it does of a nice suite of features.

Comment: Also, if you don't know, paypal offers different levels of service, depending on what you want to pay for. e.g. You can purchase a plan that does NOT require the user to leave the source site and go to their site in order to make a purchase, so the user has a more seemless (read "more trustfull") experience, and Ubercart integrates with either level nicely (after you figure out how to wade through all the configuration settings, that is).

Answer (score 2):

I have some experience, and my advice would be: why don't you find yourself a pre-made shop (such as eBay)?

Advantages over coding everything yourself are;

- easier to maintain
- no hacking risk (meaning; you won't get in trouble)
- no coding involved

(and probably a shitload of other advantages)

You could make a site with pictures of your products, and links to the eBay url. That way people can buy it on eBay, but you still have full control of your catalogi.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I thought about this. But the client wants something that is fully integrated in his website.

Comment: Then I suggest you kindly ask your client to alter his needs, since they are very... well, unhandy.

Comment: If it's only 20 products, you could just use Paypal...

Comment: I know its unhandy and I would prefer to use Ebay or alike, but its what they want and what they pay for... @redconservatory same problem